# Creating a column that has the count of elements of different column

Tags: r

I have a DF

```
 x y z
 1 1 1
 1 2 5
 2 2 5
 3 3 5
```

I would like to have a simple command in R to generate a new column of DF that is the count of my original DF and would look like the following:

```
 x y z xcount ycount zcount
 1 1 1 2      1      1
 1 2 5 2      2      3
 2 2 5 1      2      3
 3 3 5 1      1      3
```

I know this is a simple question and perhaps even the way I am thinking about it is handicapped by my previous experience with Stata. I have looked into using the `table` function but the vector which is returned by that is of length equal to the number of unique values. I could map those values to a new column in R but that seems clunky.

Comment: Are you looking for the run lengths, i.e. count consecutive values or for the total count per unique value in a column? Look at the comments under Jason's answer.

Comment: @docendodiscimus thanks for asking this - at the time I couldn't, didn't have enough rep points to post comments. Given the anwer that the OP's accepted, I conclude it was really number frequencies, disregarding their order that he was after. I changed my answer accordingly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's a long one-liner:

```
cbind(df, setNames(lapply(df, function(x) ave(x, x, FUN = length)),
  paste0(names(df), "count")))
#  x y z xcount ycount zcount
#1 1 1 1      2      1      1
#2 1 2 5      2      2      3
#3 2 2 5      1      2      3
#4 3 3 5      1      1      3
```

The important part is:

```
> lapply(df, function(x) ave(x, x, FUN = length))
$x
[1] 2 2 1 1

$y
[1] 1 2 2 1

$z
[1] 1 3 3 3
```

The rest is cosmetics.

---

You could put this in a function for easy handling:

```
dfcount <- function(df) cbind(df, setNames(lapply(df, function(x) ave(x, x, FUN = length)), paste0(names(df), "count")))
dfcount(df)
#  x y z xcount ycount zcount
#1 1 1 1      2      1      1
#2 1 2 5      2      2      3
#3 2 2 5      1      2      3
#4 3 3 5      1      1      3
```

Answer (score 2):

An option using `data.table`

```
library(data.table)
nm1 <- names(DF)
nm2 <- paste0(nm1, "count")
setDT(DF)
for(j in seq_along(nm1)) {
  DF[ , c(nm2[j]) := .N, by = c(nm1[j])]
}
DF
#   x y z xcount ycount zcount
#1: 1 1 1      2      1      1
#2: 1 2 5      2      2      3
#3: 2 2 5      1      2      3
#4: 3 3 5      1      1      3
```

Answer (score 1):

**Edit**

Based on what OP has accepted as anwser, I conclude he was looking for simple frequencies, not for "consecutive frequencies" (which incidentally happenned to give the same results in the data given as example). So I changed my answer to the following, which is consistent with the other answers given, just using a slightly different approach:

```
# With dataframe "a"
a <- read.table(text="x y z
1 1 1
1 2 5
2 2 5
3 3 5
",header=TRUE)

# cbind together the results of merging each vector with its 
# frequencies obtained from table()
a <- do.call(what = cbind, args = lapply(a, function(x) { 
    merge(x = x, y = table(x))
}))

# Remove trailing .x's from variable names
names(a) <- sub(".x", "", names(a), fixed=TRUE)

# Reorder if necessary
a <- a[,c(1,3,5,2,4,6)]

a
#   x y z x.Freq y.Freq z.Freq
# 1 1 1 1      2      1      1
# 2 1 2 5      2      2      3
# 3 2 2 5      1      2      3
# 4 3 3 5      1      1      3
```

**Previous anwser** (was assuming OP wanted consecutive frequencies)

```
a <- read.table(text="x y z
1 1 1
1 2 5
2 2 5
3 3 5
",header=TRUE)

a$countx <- rep(rle(a$x)$lengths, times=rle(a$x)$lengths)
a$county <- rep(rle(a$y)$lengths, times=rle(a$y)$lengths)
a$countz <- rep(rle(a$z)$lengths, times=rle(a$z)$lengths)
```

Results

```
#   x y z countx county countz
# 1 1 1 1      2      1      1
# 2 1 2 5      2      2      3
# 3 2 2 5      1      2      3
# 4 3 3 5      1      1      3
```

Comment: This might not be the desired result if the order was different, e.g. in column y: `c(2,1,2,3)` would give a different run length result.

Comment: Compare the difference: `x1 <- c(1,2,2,3); x2 <- c(2,1,2,3)` and then using ave: `ave(x1, x1, FUN = length); ave(x2, x2, FUN = length)` and using rle: `with(rle(x2), rep(lengths, lengths)); with(rle(x1), rep(lengths, lengths))`.

Comment: Perhaps we need some clarification from the OP. My interpretation was that they are not asking for run lengths (consecutive values) but total counts per unique element (which is also what `table` would return).

Comment: Ooooh right, then it's totally different. @fsmart can you sort this out please?